# Express $\cos2\theta$ in terms of $\cos$ and $\sin$ (De Moivre's Theorem)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polynomials

Use De Moivre's to express $\cos2\theta$ in terms of powers of $\sin$ and $\cos$.

What I have is:

$\cos2\theta + i\sin2\theta\\
= (\cos\theta + i \sin\theta)^2\\
= \cos^2\theta + 2 \cos\theta ~i \sin\theta + (i \sin)^2\theta\\
= \cos^2\theta + i(2\cos\theta \sin\theta) - \sin^2\theta\\
= \cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta + i(2\cos\theta \sin\theta)
$

so $\cos2\theta = \cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

$$\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta = (\cos\theta)(\cos\theta) - (\sin\theta)(\sin\theta)$$

$$=\cos(\theta + \theta) = \cos(2\theta)$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, indeed! Since the sine and cosine functions are real-valued functions on the reals, then since $$\cos2\theta+i\sin 2\theta=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta+i(2\sin\theta\cos\theta),$$ we have: $$\cos2\theta=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta\\\sin 2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

using de moivres theorem we can generalise.$$\cos(n\theta)=\cos^n(\theta)-\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\cos^{n-2}(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4!} \cos^{n-4}(\theta)\sin^4(\theta)........$$

Answer (score -2):

Here is a geometric proof:

- the triangle ABC is isosceles $AB = AC = r$ and equiangular with equal angles at B and C
- the angle at A being $2\theta$, both angles at B and C equal $\pi/2-\theta$
- the height = perpendicular bisector from A to BC meets the latter at D
- the height perpendicular from C to AB meets the latter at H
- now express the length of AH first as cathetus of rectangular triangle CAH
- and then as difference of AB and HB. HB is a cathetus in rectangular triangle BCH.
  Putting this together we get
  $$\cos2\theta = 1-2\sin^2\theta$$
  Using $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$ (Pythagoras) the equivalent expressions
  $$\cos2\theta = \cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1$$ are as well obtained.

[image]